# шаблонизация master/slave с ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

есть два хотста в инвентори файле. требуется с использованием шаблонизатора при первой итерации плэйбука установить IP в шаблон из второй итерации. при второй итерации установить ip из первой. возможно ли это сделать в ansible?

Comment: Если честно - я нихрена не понял. Можно, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее и развёрнутее? И главное - зачем.

Comment: Возможно если храниш кеш в json. Потом просто сурсай из него. Вопрос благорднешего в силе - нахрена вам это?